# Insert data to database

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

I got a problem when inserting a data. When I click the add button this are always comes out "Error Sir" which is this one `die ('Error Sir' . mysql_error())`.

But when I tried to look for my database everything what I inserted was there.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 
$add = $_POST['add']; //Add button
$date = $_POST['date'];
$project = $_POST['project'];
$task = $_POST['task'];
$originated = $_POST['originated'];
$incharge = $_POST['incharge'];
$deadline = $_POST['deadline'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$fin = $_POST['fin'];
//If add button click
if ($add)
{
    //This is for checkbox group
    if(is_array($incharge))
        {
        foreach($incharge as $val2)
            {
                $tstring = implode(', ' , $incharge);

                //Database Connection
                $con = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
                if (!$con)
                {
                    die ('Not connected to DB' . mysql_error());
                }
                //Selecting Database
                mysql_select_db ("profound_master", $con);
                //Adding of data to te Database
                $sql = "INSERT INTO bulletin VALUES ('','$date','$project','$task','$originated','$tstring','$deadline','$status','$comment','$fin')"; 


                if (!mysql_query ($sql, $con));
                {
                    die ('Error Sir' . mysql_error()); //Always stop here

                }
                echo "1 record added";

                mysql_close($con);          
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: i suggest finding out what the actual return value is from the mysql_query call.  seems like you are catching a valid transaction in the if...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested, try to find out the error you are getting before anything else. Also make sure the data you have in the database is actually the data you are currently inserting. I'm almost sure you have the same data already in the database and you THINK you are inserting new values.

Answer (score 1):

remove the ";" after the condition of the if

```
    if (!mysql_query ($sql, $con))
    {
           die ('Error Sir' . mysql_error()); //Always stop here
    }
```

Comment: I hate when I put a semi-colon where it shouldn't be, it can lead to errors which are flagged many liens away from the offending line.

Comment: Thank you! now it is connected. but i got a follow up problem regarding to the databse. When i click the add button it says "1 record added" 4 times. i think the problem now is my checkbox group. because when i check 3 items to my checkbox group the data stored 3 time with same data.

Comment: makes sense ... you need to check whether the check box is checked or not before inserting

Comment: All i want is to put all what ive selected or check in a one field. just like this. "a, b, c," but always happened are if i check a and c what i insert was duplicated in the database. Thank you so much and Sorry to trouble you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use the columns):

```
INSERT INTO bulletin (`column1`,`column2`,`youGetThePoint...`) VALUES ('',$date,$project)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume first parameter is your ID

try to insert 0

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bulletin VALUES (0,'$date','$project','$task','$originated','$tstring','$deadline','$status','$comment','$fin')";
```

if not, try adding `mysql_errno()`:

```
die('Error Sir' . mysql_errno($con) . ': ' . mysql_error($con));
```

and also try to format your inputs `'".$date."','".$project."',....`